# Explain the ! and [] usage in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've read several books on Excel and Access VBA already, but I'm still not quite clear about the usage of `[]` and `!`, eg. like the `!` in the third line in the following code.

Can anybody generously enumerate some examples of how to use `[]` and `!`.

```access
Sub modApp_ListTempvars()
' Set some example temporary variables
TempVars!FormName = "frmScreenForm"
TempVars.Add "Current User", Application.CurrentUser
' list all values for temporary variables
Dim tv As TempVar
Debug.Print "Listing TempVars" & TempVars.Count
Debug.Print "________________"
For Each tv In TempVars
Debug.Print tv.Name, tv.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`!` is shorthand for accessing collections such as forms, fields or controls

`Forms!MyForm` is the same as  `Forms("MyForm")`

`CurrentDb!MyTable!MyField` is the same as `CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTable").Fields("MyField")`

`[]` is used to enclose a property or field that contains spaces. Without the enclosing brackets the parser would not know how to parse it.

Suppose you have a control called `Area Code`

You would use the following syntax to refer to it:

```
MyForm.[Area Code].Forecolor = ...
```

Suppose you have field in your table called `Date of birth`

You would use the following SQL to query it:

```
SELECT Firstname, Surname, [Date of birth] FROM tbl
```